# How to select an element on Kittl website

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Sorry for my English.

I am developing an automate extension for Cava,Photopea and Kittl.

Our chrome extension will read value from csv file and auto replace text on a design.
Example: I am designing a template for T-SHIRT and I have two text element "Name", "Slogan" on this design.
In the CSV file, I list the values for Name and Slogan. Our app will find and replace text , then save as result as png.

I have implemented my idea successfully for Cana and Photopea, but cannot for Kittl.
The problem is I couldn't see these elements on HTML page when I inspected. Therefore, I cannot use javascript to select these elememts and replace text.

[T-Shirt Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eegFG.png)

I thought they are using canvas HTML, but I tried to get a context and fill a text but its failed.
I am wonder how they hide these elements and what is the solution to select a element on design of Kittl.

Comment: Please provide example code and work on Kittl.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is simply not possible. Kittl uses an `HTMLCanvasElement` to render its graphics. Canvases do not expose references to document-like structures where you can query elements. At most you can inspect "baked" pixel data, or programmatically draw new stuff on top what already exists.